# Android DownloadManager Handle Notification Click Event on Completed Download

Tags: android, download, notifications, mp3

I have a problem trying to handle notification click events for downloaded **.mp3** files. I already registered the following:

- DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED - I only get the callback from the broadcast receiver when clicking on a notification item that's **currently being downloaded** (still running).
- DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE - I get the callback when download completes

The problem is, when I click on a **completed** download, I get a list of apps that can handle that download **.mp3** file (like VLC).

Is there a way to restrict the notification item click so that it's only handled by my app? By the way, my app doesn't even show in the list.

P.S.
Would be nice if the solution didn't involve having to create my custom notification handling.

**Edit 1:**
Here's the code to start the download:

```
private void downloadRequest(int position, String url, String title, String description, String filename) {

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.setDescription(description);
    request.setTitle(title);
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

    try {
        request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(FileUtils.getAudioDirectory(getActivity()) + filename)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    enqueue = mDownloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

As per matty357's request, here's my broadcast receiver for the notification click:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiverNotificationClicked = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String extraId = DownloadManager.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_CLICK_DOWNLOAD_IDS;
        long[] references = intent.getLongArrayExtra(extraId);
        for(long reference : references) {
            AppLog.d("DOWNLOAD_MANAGER", "reference (clicked): " + reference);
        }
        AppLog.d("DOWNLOAD_MANAGER", "Received click");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution for this is to put:

```
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
```

So you won't have a notification when download is finished. And:

```
context.registerReceiver(onComplete,
            new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

So you will be able to put a notification when download is completed.

```
BroadcastReceiver onComplete=new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onComplete");
        // AND HERE SET YOUR ONW NOTIFICATION WHICH YOU WILL ABLE TO HANDLE
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could open it yourself programmatically.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File("/sdcard/test.mp4");
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");
startActivity(intent); 

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File("/sdcard/test.mp3");
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

use intent.setPackage("packageName")

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage(java.lang.String)

Comment: Doesn't work, matty357. I still get a list of "Complete action using" without my app.  Still shows VLC, etc.

Comment: Could you please post the chunk of code that is being used in your clicked receiver.

Comment: Not sure how that's helpful, though, as I stated above, that works fine if the download is still in progress - I get the click event, since I registered for the DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED.

Comment: it was so we can see what you are doing when the click occurs

Comment: Okay, it's only logging stuff. But posted my receiver as well as how I start the download.

Comment: By the way, not sure where to put the intent.setPackage() method, since I'm using the downloadRequest() to start the download.